# PGF Gantt, group label inside

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfgantt, gantt

When using the ' inline ' option for a ganttgroup, the label is written above the group. I would like to thicken (this can be done with the parameter group height) the group and that the naming of the label appear **inside** the group. I am struggling with the " group inline label node " parameters but did not manage to produce what I want. Here's an example to illustrate what I would like to do.

The code below produces this diagram. I would like to have " Label of the group " written inside the gray area (centered, if possible).

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}


\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usepackage{color}
\colorlet{mylightgray}{gray!35}

\begin{document}
\ganttset{milestone/.append style={red,rounded corners=5pt},
progress label node anchor/.append style={text=red}}

\begin{ganttchart}[
 x unit = 0.9cm,
 y unit title=0.5cm,
 y unit chart=0.7cm,
 vgrid, hgrid,
 title height=1,
 group right shift=0,
 group top shift=0.1,
 group height=0.7,
 group peaks width={0.2},
 group/.append style={fill=lightgray},
 ]{1}{6}
\gantttitle[]{2022}{3}    \gantttitle[]{2023}{3}\\
    \gantttitle{Jan}{1}
\gantttitle{Juin}{1}
\gantttitle{Oct}{1}
    \gantttitle{Jan}{1}
    \gantttitle{Juin}{1}
    \gantttitle{Oct}{1}
    \\
    \ganttgroup[inline=true]{Label of the group}{3}{6}\\
         \\
  \end{ganttchart}


\end{document}
```

Thanks for any help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the option

```
group inline label node/.style={yshift=0pt,font=\bfseries}
```

to the `ganttchart` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usepackage{color}
\colorlet{mylightgray}{gray!35}

\begin{document}
\ganttset{milestone/.append style={red,rounded corners=5pt},
progress label node anchor/.append style={text=red}}

\begin{ganttchart}[
 x unit = 0.9cm,
 y unit title=0.5cm,
 y unit chart=0.7cm,
 vgrid, hgrid,
 title height=1,
 group right shift=0,
 group top shift=0.1,
 group height=0.7,
 group peaks width={0.2},
 group/.append style={fill=lightgray},
 group inline label node/.style={yshift=0pt,font=\bfseries}
 ]{1}{6}
    \gantttitle[]{2022}{3}    \gantttitle[]{2023}{3}\\
    \gantttitle{Jan}{1}
    \gantttitle{Juin}{1}
    \gantttitle{Oct}{1}
    \gantttitle{Jan}{1}
    \gantttitle{Juin}{1}
    \gantttitle{Oct}{1} \\
    \ganttgroup[inline]{Label of the group}{3}{6}\\
     \\
\end{ganttchart}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, @gernot !